# Mysql Match...against query performance in InnoDB Mysql 5.6

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.6

I need to search records in the table which contains millions of records. I have recently updated Mysql version from 5.1 to 5.6.

I was using `like` in query which was taking around 15 sec to 30 sec.

Currently I have modified query to use `MATCH... AGAINST` feature of mysql 5.6 INNODB. My query goes like this.

```
SELECT JOB.IDJOB, JOB.IDEMPLOYER ..... FROM JOB WHERE  (  ( JOB.ITJOBSTARTTYPE=2 AND JOB.DTPLANNEDEND >= '2015-07-06' ) OR  ( JOB.ITJOBSTARTTYPE=1 AND ( ( JOB.ITJOBENDTYPE=2 ) OR ( JOB.DTJOBEND>='2015-07-06') ) ) OR  ( JOB.ITJOBSTARTTYPE=3 AND ( (JOB.DTJOBEND >='2015-07-06') OR (JOB.ITJOBENDTYPE=2) ) )  ) AND MATCH(VCJOBTITLE, LVJOBCOMPANYDESCRIPTION, VCCOMPANYNAME, VCSALARYDESC, VCCITY, VCQUALIFICATIONREQUIRED,VCJOBREFERENCE, LVJOBKEYWORDS ) AGAINST ('test'   IN NATURAL LANGUAGE MODE) ORDER BY JOB.ITJOBBAND ASC,JOB.VCRANKING DESC,JOB.IDJOB DESC,JOB.FJOBWEIGHT ASC LIMIT 50;
```

Which takes 80- 120 seconds (3X slower )

If I remove `ORDER BY` it will load in 6 to 10 sec.

Is their any setting Or performance tunning we can apply here?

EDIT:

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE JOB;


     CREATE TABLE `JOB` (
  `idJob` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `idEmployer` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcJobTitle` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `lvJobCompanyDescription` text,
  `idBasket` int(10) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dtActualgolive` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'whenever job status become online',
  `boImmediatelygolive` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dtRequestedgolive` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dtActualend` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'when job is set to be archieved',
  `dtPlannedend` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'when posting a job this is calculated. batch will look at this date. date on which regular jobs will be archievd, or date on which internship jobs will be changed to listing',
  `dtRequestedend` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'exact date on which employer wants jobs to be archieved',
  `dtApplicationdeadline` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'job will be converted to listing on this date',
  `boDurationinweeks` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'whether employer gave duration in weeks or not',
  `itDurationweeks` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boIsoncredit` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `dtCreditend` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `fJobbaseprice` float NOT NULL,
  `fJobpriceafteradminitemdiscount` float NOT NULL COMMENT 'price after admin item discount',
  `fJobpriceafterpromodiscount` float NOT NULL COMMENT 'price after promo discount',
  `vcPromotioncode` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcCompanyname` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `vcSalarydesc` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `vcCity` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `vcCounty` varchar(120) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcQualificationrequired` text,
  `boWorkfromhome` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boResidential` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boIndoor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boOutdoor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boIndoorandoutdoor` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `itJobstarttype` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'date,immidiate,always recruiting',
  `dtJobstart` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `itJobendtype` int(11) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'date,ongoing',
  `dtJobend` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dtFeaturedstart` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `dtFeaturedend` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `itFulltimeparttime` int(11) NOT NULL COMMENT 'fulltime,parttime,both',
  `boEveningtime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boDaytime` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boWeekend` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boNewsletter` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vcApplyemail` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcApplyphone` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcApplyaddress` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcApplyURL` varchar(500) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boRequirephone` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boRequireaddress` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boRequirecv` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boFeatured` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `blLogo` longblob,
  `itJobstatus` int(1) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'online,offline',
  `itEmailedtofriendcount` int(5) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'keeps count of how many times users clicked on link email this to friend',
  `itDeadlinetype` int(1) DEFAULT NULL,
  `idInternshiptypemaster` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcLengthofscheme` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `dtInternshiplistingend` date DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'date when internship job will archieve',
  `itJobband` int(2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boGraduate` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boInternship` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boGaptemp` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boParttimeholiday` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `boEntrylevel` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `boHundredPercentDiscountApplicable` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `vcContactdetails` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `vcJobreference` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'for importing totaljobs feeds',
  `vcJoburlparam` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'for importing totaljobs url params',
  `dtPutInCurrentBand` datetime DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'date when job is online and put in band 3',
  `itInitcountycount` int(2) NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `updated_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `lvJobkeywords` text,
  `fJobweight` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT '1.00' COMMENT 'Holds the job weight ranging between 0 to 1 (1 being the highest weight)',
  `dtReinstatedOn` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `boIncludeiniframe` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `boIsAdvertFeatured` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `itincludexml` int(1) DEFAULT '1',
  `boAddtojobalert` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  `vcRanking` int(11) DEFAULT '999999',
  `itIncludeUkptj` int(11) DEFAULT '1',
  PRIMARY KEY (`idJob`),
  KEY `JOB_I_1` (`idEmployer`,`itJobstatus`),
  KEY `JOB_I_2` (`itJobstatus`,`boGaptemp`,`dtJobstart`),
  KEY `JOB_I_3` (`itJobstatus`,`boGraduate`,`dtJobstart`),
  KEY `JOB_I_4` (`itJobstatus`,`boInternship`,`dtJobstart`),
  KEY `JOB_I_5` (`itJobstatus`,`boParttimeholiday`,`dtJobstart`),
  KEY `FI_JOB_idOrder_ORDER_idOrder` (`idBasket`),
  KEY `FI_JOB_vcPromotioncode_PROMOTION_vcPromotioncode` (`vcPromotioncode`),
  KEY `FI_JOB_idInternshiptype_ITTM_idInternshiptypemaster` (`idInternshiptypemaster`),
  KEY `JOB_I_6` (`created_at`),
  KEY `boEntrylevel` (`boEntrylevel`),
  KEY `itJobband` (`itJobband`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `index_ft_search` (`vcJobTitle`,`lvJobCompanyDescription`,`vcCompanyname`,`vcSalarydesc`,`vcCity`,`vcQualificationrequired`,`vcJobreference`,`lvJobkeywords`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_idEmployer_EMPLOYER_idEmployer` FOREIGN KEY (`idEmployer`) REFERENCES `EMPLOYER` (`idEmployer`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_idInternshiptype_ITTM_idInternshiptypemaster` FOREIGN KEY (`idInternshiptypemaster`) REFERENCES `INTERNSHIPTYPEMASTER` (`idInternshiptypemaster`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_idOrder_ORDER_idOrder` FOREIGN KEY (`idBasket`) REFERENCES `BASKET` (`idBasket`),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_JOB_vcPromotioncode_PROMOTION_vcPromotioncode` FOREIGN KEY (`vcPromotioncode`) REFERENCES `PROMOTION` (`vcPromotioncode`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1739324 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

With EXPLAIN without SORT:

[image]

With EXPLAIN with SORT:

[image]

Comment: please provide your table structure using `SHOW  CREATE TABLE job; `

Comment: @Masoud : edited question

Comment: can you add the `Explain` result for your query as well? once with sort and once without

Comment: Added screenshots of phpmyadmin for explain query

Comment: When you use fulltext index to find rows it has no order specified, and no other "normal" index can be used, so your query with order by has to do filesort on all matching rows to give you "top 50", seems like the string 'test' is matching quite a lot of rows.

Comment: Any solution for that? We can't skip ORDERBY opton.

Comment: Without limit and order by it will take around 5mins. 63602 rows in set retrieved.

Comment: How many rows are there in the table? Are results this big expected from normal queries or is it just specific to 'test' and similar words?

Comment: Table contain 1million + records. Normally we will display 20 records per page. We are expecting 20-40 thousand results per query.

Comment: Ok, that is a lot of results to sort, and when you select many columns, the temporary table used for sorting it is big. And as I can see in your EXPLAIN, you have many DEPENDENT subqueries - those are evaluated once per row so 20-40k times for each of them. I have a suggestion: Use the FULLTEXT index to get only primary keys of rows you want (as a derived table maybe), and then do the remaining part of the query to use different index for sorting. Or fetch only PKs, but sorted and filtered by all conditions, that way temp table to sort will be small, then LIMIT and get your 20 records in full.